# includes...and/or?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

> An activity that does not contain other activities is called an atomic
>   activity, which includes invocation, receive, **and** reply
>   activities.
>
> An activity that does not contain other activities is called an atomic
>   activity, which includes invocation, receive, **or** reply activities.

May I know which one is grammatical?

Comment: I guess you should provide more context. The way two sentences are right now it's hard to tell which of them is correct.

Comment: @MARamezani you can consider the three activities as three unrelated activities for different functionalities, but they are all categorized as atomic activities.

Answer (score 2):

> I ate cheese **and** toast for my breakfast.

Both "cheese" and "toast" were eaten for breakfast.

> Should I eat toast **or** cheese for my breakfast?

I either have to choose between "cheese" and "toast". I can't eat both. it's always about eating. :)

Now that we have that clear, let's cut to the chase:

> An activity that does not contain other activities is called an atomic activity, which includes invocation, receive, and reply activities.

"Reply activities", "invocation activities", and "receive activities" are all 'parts' of "atomic activity", as you mentioned. If there's an "and" between the sub-level notions, it could mean that "atomic activity" is a big circle with smaller shapes in it, shown below:[image: Atomic activities]

> An activity that does not contain other activities is called an atomic activity, which includes invocation, receive, or reply activities.

The main idea of the last clause (the ones that begins with the relative pronoun "which") is atomic activity 'including' something. The meaning of the clause would be

> Atomic activity can't have all of the three ideas at the same time, if it includes "receive" then it must not include "reply".

Since all are categorized under "atomic activity", so the second one isn't true. If we talk about grammaticality, both "and" and "or" have their unique functions, but here; it's good to use "and"; so the 1st statement is what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Using *and* is preferable; it's common to use *and* when compiling a list of options. But you will find that most people in general have a poor understanding of the subtle differences in *and* versus *or*.

When my son wants a snack I might permit him to have just one by saying:

> *You can choose between chips and candy.*
>
> *You can have chips or candy.*

Here's where it starts to get confusing:

> *You can choose between chips or candy.* (Quite wrong to me, but you'll hear people say it.)
>
> *You can have chips and candy.* (Am I allowing him to have both or am I just sloppy with language? You'll be likely to hear this as well but I think it's clearly ambiguous.)

Just yesterday a radio show host I was listening to felt the need to clarify what he meant when he was talking about a proposed ban on "texting and driving." Naturally the legislation was intended to target people who do both at the same time and not two separate bans on the individual activities. I see this kind of confusion a lot in my work as a software developer so I pay close attention to it.